# Do we need the [slow] tag?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[slow](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/slow) …

> Something that is not fast or moving at a slow pace.

276 questions tagged. But does it add any value? Seems like a classical meta-tag to me. If something is slow, then we already tag it with *whatever it is*. Plus, we have a much more meaningful [performance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance) anyway.

Please just get rid of it, Trogdor!

[image]

Comment: Also: [`[fast]`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fast)

Comment: this was part of my tags-that-need-to-be-cleaned list. http://i.imm.io/ovjx.png Should arrange for a massive crowdsourced cleanup

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We could just ball up all the speed related tags into the performance class and be done with it.

Which leads us to this:

- fast was removed from 23 questions
- slow was removed from 307 questions

Both now map to [performance](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/performance).